# Django: How do I get logging working?

Tags: python, django, logging

I've added the following to my settings.py file:

```
import logging
...
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename=os.path.join(rootdir, 'django.log'),
    filemode='a+')
```

And in views.py, I've added:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
log.info("testing 123!")
```

Unfortunately, no log file is being created. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? And also is their a better method I should be using for logging? I am doing this on Webfaction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python logging in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342434/python-logging-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python logging for Django is fine on somewhere like Webfaction. If you were on a cloud-based provider (eg Amazon EC2) where you had a number of servers, it might be worth looking at either logging to key-value DB or using Python logging over the network.

Your logging setup code in settings.py looks fine, but I'd check that you can write to `rootdir` -- your syslog might show errors, but it's more likely that Django would be throwing a 500 if it couldn't log properly.

Which leads me to note that the only major difference in my logging (also on WebFaction) is that I do:

```
import logging
logging.info("Something here")
```

instead of `log.info`

Comment: Don't know why, but changing to logging.info did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the original `log.info()` should have worked, because you (@FunLovinCoder) started a new instance of a logger with `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Mine works fine and it's the same...