# Why does a python module act like a singleton?

Tags: python, singleton

I create a dictionary from a remote database as part of my application run.  This process is pretty I/O heavy, so I've decided to create a "singleton" instance of this dictionary and just call it as it is needed in my application.

The code looks like (in `Dictionaries.py`):

```
state_code_dict = None

def get_state_code_dict():
    global state_code_dict
    if state_code_dict == None:
        state_code_dict = generate_state_code_dict()
    return state_code_dict
```

I then import and call the `get_state_code_dict()` function where needed.  I added a print statement to check if `state_code_dict` was being reinitialized or reused, and I found it was being reused (which is the functionality I want).  Why is the instance of `state_code_dict` surviving the application run?

**Edit**

I import the `get_state_code_dict` function in multiple files.

Comment: because imported code gets executed only the first time?

Comment: edited to clarify: I import the code in multiple locations (multiple files include the `get_state_code_dict` function.

Comment: Importing code that the interpreter has already loaded will not re-load that code by default.  It's possible to deliberately reload a module but if you have to do this for any reason other than because the actual code of the module might have changed during runtime, you should probably use a different programming idiom to do what you want to do.

Comment: And this behavior is desirable precisely because module initialization is sometimes heavyweight.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the Python Language Reference's description of [how importing a module works](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> (1) find a module, and initialize it *if necessary*; (2) define a name or names in the local namespace

(Emphasis added.) Here, *initializing* a module means executing its code. This execution is only performed *if necessary*, i.e. if the module was not previously imported in the current process. Since Python modules are first-class runtime objects, they effectively become singletons, initialized at the time of first import.

Note that this means that there's no need for a `get_state_dict_code` function; just initialize `state_code_dict` at top-level:

```
state_code_dict = generate_state_code_dict()
```

For a more in-depth explanation, see [this talk by Thomas Wouters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOzdG3lwcB4), esp. the first part — around 04:20 — where he discusses the "everything is runtime" principle.

Comment: Would I then get the state_code_dict by calling `import Dictionaries; state_code_dict = Dictionaries.state_code_dict`?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt: yes. Or by the idiomatic `from Dictionaries import state_code_dict`.

Answer (score 14):

I voted larsmans answer, i just wanted to add an example.

**hello.py:**

```
hi = 'hello'

print(hi)

def print_hi():
    print(hi)
```

**ipython session:**

```
In [1]: from hello import print_hi
hello

In [2]: print_hi()
hello

In [3]: from hello import print_hi

In [4]: import hello

In [5]: hello.print_hi()
hello
```

Look that the imports at lines 3 and 4 don't output "hello" as the import in line 1 did, that means the code isn't re-executed.