# Multiple instances of a global module variable?

Tags: python

Background: I'm working with a device vendor-supplied API module which stores device login data (device hostname, session ID, etc) as a global variable; I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have multiple instances of the module to represent logins to multiple devices.

So far I've attempted a couple strategies with test code, none of which have worked:

Test module code: statictest.py

```
count = 0

class Test():
  @classmethod
  def testcount(cls):
    global count
    count += 1
    return count
```

First attempt: import module multiple times and instantiate:

```
>>> import statictest as s1
>>> import statictest as s2
>>> s1.Test.testcount()
1 
>>> s1.Test.testcount()
2
>>> s2.Test.testcount()
3
```

Second try: import module inside class, instantiate class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
class TestMod():
  s = __import__('statictest')

  def test(self):
    ts = self.s.Test()
    return ts.testcount()

t = TestMod()
u = TestMod()
print t.test()
print u.test()
```

That one didn't work either:

```
[~/]$ ./moduletest.py 
1
2
```

This seems like it *should* be obvious but is there any way to encapsulate a module such that multiple instances are available?

Comment: No. If you want multiple instances, you should be using a class, not a module-level value. Your vendor is behaving (very) badly by putting this state at the module level.

Comment: Please file a bug with your vendor. This is broken by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work. It uses your `statictest.py` module and a combination of a few of the ideas in other answers to create a context manager which will allow easy switching and use of any of the various instances of the module:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import importlib
import random
import sys

MODULE_NAME = 'statictest'
NUM_INSTANCES = 4
instances = []

# initialize module instances
for _ in xrange(NUM_INSTANCES):
    if MODULE_NAME in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules[MODULE_NAME]

    module = importlib.import_module(MODULE_NAME)
    for _ in xrange(random.randrange(10)): # call testcount a random # of times
        module.Test.testcount()

    instances.append(sys.modules[MODULE_NAME])

@contextmanager
def statictest_inst(n):
    save = sys.modules[MODULE_NAME]
    sys.modules[MODULE_NAME] = instances[n]
    yield instances[n]
    sys.modules[MODULE_NAME] = save

def get_counts():
    counts = []
    for i in xrange(NUM_INSTANCES):
        with statictest_inst(i) as inst:
            counts.append(inst.count)
    return counts

print 'initial counts', get_counts()

choice = random.randrange(NUM_INSTANCES)
print 'calling instance[{}].testcount()'.format(choice)
with statictest_inst(choice) as inst: # use context manager
    inst.Test.testcount()

print 'counts after updating one of them', get_counts()
```

Sample output:

```
initial counts [2, 4, 4, 1]
calling instance[2].testcount()
counts after updating one of them [2, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible because Python modules pretty much behave like Singletons (in fact this is a valid method to create a Singleton in Python). [Refer to this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936709/why-does-a-python-module-act-like-a-singleton) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) for example. This design is intended to prevent multiple imports of the same module because it can be somewhat expensive. The `logging` module is an excellent example of this. You set up your logger once and all your code which is being run by the same interpreter and imports `logging` will write to the same logfile.

Answer (score 1):

Between imports, you can delete the module from `sys.modules` to force it to be re-imported:

```
import sys
import module
del sys.modules['module']
import module as module2
print(module is module2) # prints False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make copies of the file (statictest1.py, statictest2.py) that will work:

```
>>> import sttest1 as s1
>>> import sttest2 as s2
>>> s1.Test.testcount()
1
>>> s1.Test.testcount()
2
>>> s1.Test.testcount()
3
>>> s2.Test.testcount()
1
>>> s2.Test.testcount()
2
>>> s2.Test.testcount()
```

Comment: Note:  This works if the second file is just a link to the first one, so you could dynamically create links and then import the 'new' file.  Kind of odd, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the module's state is really well contained, you could write a context manager to swap the global state in and out of the module (i.e. monkey patch it) when you call it.

For instance:

```
import mymodule

class ModuleState(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.global_state = mymodule.global_state

    def __enter__(self):
        my_module.global_state = self.global_state
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        my_module.global_state = default_state

default_state = mymodule.global_state

# Init mymodule for state1
state1 = ModuleState()

# Init mymodule for state2
state2 = ModuleState()

# Init mymodule for state3
state3 = ModuleState()


# Do something in state2
with state2:
    mymodule.something()
```