# Processes spawned using multiprocessing module access the same copy of function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code which looks like following:

```
import some_module
def foo(f):
  //do something
  some_module.func()

jobs = [mp.Process(target=foo, args=(f,)) for f in files]

for job in jobs:
    job.start()

for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

So, each process spawned has its own copy of `foo` function but all the processes try to access the same copy of the function `some_module.func()`
  My requirement is that each process have separate copy of `foo` and `some_module.func()` so that one process does not hinder progress of another process.

Comment: And what's your question exactly ?

Comment: The processes which are spawned are using the same copy of 'some_module.func()'. For example, suppose 'some_module.func()' is creating an instance of webdriver, so what is happening that all process are using same webdriver instance instead of creating there own instances. It means all processes are accessing same copy of  'some_module.func()' . Hope that clears a bit.

Comment: I think you will need to give more detail, and an example that demonstrates your point. No process shares the same modules or functions with any other process. Separate processes only share memory unless specifically requested (by using the classes provided by multiprocessing).

Comment: Ok. I will post my original code that may give a better insight.

Comment: Modules are singletones in python. Instead of calling "some_module.func()" you should consider defining a class inside "some_module" which when instantiated within the "foo" function will provide the "func" function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936709/why-does-a-python-module-act-like-a-singleton , I guess it'll tell you something.