# Is import Dynamic or Static

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my main script, I import one of my own module which contains global variables. This main script execute another script with the function exec (`exec(compile(open(Seq_1, "rb").read(), Seq_1, 'exec'))` and this other script import the same module.
So my question is: does these scripts have access to the same global variables (that means if I modify one global variable, the other script will be impacted) or not?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Python will run your file when you first import it. On the second import python won't re-run the file.

In practice, python functions and variables directly on modules (not wrapped in classes) works like singletons.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936709/why-does-a-python-module-act-like-a-singleton) explains more about it. You can directly refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), also suggested on linked answer.